# What is the $4k$ kernelization algorithm for Planar Independent Set?

Tags: parameterized-complexity

[Chen et al.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.1808&rep=rep1&type=pdf) say that

> The four-color theorem implies a $4k$-kernelization for Planar Independent Det, which is the dual problem of Planar Vertex Cover.

I knew that Vertex Cover has a kernelization with $2k$ vertices.  Furthermore, I know that we have a lower bound which is $n/4$ for IS.

But how to get a $4k$ vertex kernel for Planar IS?  Is there a general rule that when we transform "primal" program to "dual" program, then we have a factor of 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formal problem is:

- Input: A planar graph $G = (V, E)$ and an integer $k$ (the parameter)
- Question: Does $G$ have an independent set of size at least $k$?

**A kernelization algorithm for Planar IS** with $4k$ vertices.

Recall that we can obtain a four-coloring of $G$ in polynomial time.  That is, we get a partitioning of your vertex set $V$ into $V_1, V_2, V_3, V_4$ such that each class is an independent set.

We now distinguish between two cases:

- One class $V_i$ has size at least $k$.  This is a witness and hence $G,k$ is a yes instance, so we may output a trivial yes instance.
- Otherwise, every class has size less than $k$, so $V$ has at most $4k-4$ vertices.

Thus in polynomial time, we may output a graph $G'$ with at most $4k$ vertices such that $G,k$ is a yes instance if and only if $G', k$ is a yes instance.

Notice that *this only holds for planar graphs.*  Independent Set is W[1]-hard on general graphs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is really nice answer. I have a question: when we partition the vertices into four groups based on the colors. Do you mean that we use linear relaxation for example: V_1 for color 1 V_2 for color 2, etc as we did in vertex cover where we use {1,0,1/2}-partition of vertices. Because I just see your answer has no common with the idea of Vertex cover has kernel of 2k. Another question: it is not always that one color of the graph will be maximum independent (or even maximal) so it is ok, right

Comment: No, we don't use any linear programming tools, at all, so actually, just forget about LP, duality and even vertex cover.  The four-coloring algorithm partitions the graph into four independent sets.  You don't necessarily get the maximum independent set.  But all we cared about was whether there was one of size at least $k$.

Comment: It is very clear now, thank you so much!